# What's the difference between BigInteger.Pow() and Math.Pow()?

Tags: c#, numeric

I found the following execution of those code snippets to be kinda confusing :

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.Pow(1000, 1000);
```

this will compile with no errors however this one wont :

```
BigInteger result = (BigInteger)Math.Pow(1000, 1000);
```

What's the difference between the implementation of `BigInteger.Pow()` and `Math.Pow()`. In both cases we are `using System.Numerics`.

The second one throws *OverflowException BigInteger cannot represent infinity.*

Comment: As far as I know, Math is used on normal data types, whereas BigInteger is its own special type, which is just multiple integers put together and as such can not have the same functions used on it - hence it has its own set (The Math data methods overflow when calculating this as they use standard data types which **cannot** hold values big enough for this calculation, whereas BigInteger methods use BigIntegers to do the calculation)

Comment: what does the error tell you ..does it give you this when trying to run it 
`BigInteger cannot represent infinity.`

Comment: Is the documentation unclear? How so?

Comment: Pretty sure both snippets can compile. The error is runtime.

Comment: Yes you are right. But  I said the second one wont compile without errors not that it wont compile at all.

Comment: You mean it won't RUN without errors. It will compile just fine.

Comment: @KOPEUE It will _compile_ but t won't _run_ without errors.  It's important to understand the difference when diagnosing a problem.

Comment: English is not my native language please excuse me for any mistakes I make. Yes I meant that it will compile but it will have errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1000^1000` is out of range of a `double`, so when you call `Math.Pow(1000,1000)` it returns `double.PositiveInfinity`.

You cannot assign `double.PositiveInfinity` to a `BigInteger`, hence the error.